# Use loading bar for WebBrowser control on WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

is there a way to create a loading bar similar to the loading bar in native IE on the phone? I know we have the progressbar control, but this does not show how much of the page has been downloaded and sometimes appears like the app is running endlessly. Or maybe there is a way to use the progressbar control in this manner? Any help, suggestions, or references would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default WebBrowser control doesn't offer any public way to keep track of the progress, therefore you either will have to bind to an event handler to show that the page is loading (without any progress indication whatsoever) - e.g. `Navigating` or use a non-browser method to download specific data (e.g. through `HttpWebRequest`).